# Publishing Feature Services from spatial view on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, feature-service

I have a feature class layer and a handful of non spatial plain tables in a 10.1 ArcSDE geodatabase on MS SQL Server. What I want to achieve is to publish a feature service from ArcGIS Server so as for users to edit both features and attributes from the non spatial tables.

I tried to make a spatial view by joining the feature table with other non-spatial tables by referencing foreign keys. I was able to publish the spatial view as feature service but not to  make any edits from the REST service (Add, Update, Delete).

Just wondering why this was not successful and if a spatial view cannot be edited through feature service?

Comment: How have you made the spatial View? If you are using a Select in the View statement, then, by definition, it is Read-Only View, and Editing is not possible, even from SQL.